# protecting Admin routes Angular || TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAdmin' of null

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication

am working with Angular 11.2.12 using Firebase 9.10.2. I am currently new to Angular. I am taking course of Mosh Hamedani from codewithmosh. But the problem is I'm using angular 11 and the tutorial I'm watching in Angular4.

Now I am working with protecting admin routes. Where some credentials are define in firebase.

I have to work with show and hide features if the user is admin.

**1) Here is the data define about the user in firebase.**

```
email:safsaf@dkaj.com
isAdmin: false
name: "jashandeep"
```

**2) user.service.ts**

```
get(uid: string): AngularFireObject<AppUser> {
return this.db.object('/users/' + uid);
}
```

**3) app-user.ts**

```
export interface AppUser {
name: string;
email: string;
isAdmin: boolean;
}
```

**4) admin-auth-guard.service.ts**

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
return this.auth.user$.pipe(
  switchMap((user) => {
    return this.userService.get(user.uid).valueChanges();
  }),
  map((appUser) => appUser.isAdmin)
 );
}
```

**5) auth.service.ts**

```
 constructor(
private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
private route: ActivatedRoute
) {
 this.user$ = afAuth.authState;
}

login() {

let returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl') || '/';
localStorage.setItem('returnUrl', returnUrl);

this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
}

logout() {
this.afAuth.signOut();
}
```

**Getting error:  core.js:6210 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAdmin' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAdmin' of null**

***But isAdmin property is already defined in firebase as you can see above***

Comment: Does the error occure on `map((appUser) => appUser.isAdmin)` ? I think the `null` data is `appUser`, and not `isAdmin`

Comment: so any suggestion what should i do..I am struck here.

Comment: What does `map((appUser) => { console.log(appUser); return appUser.isAdmin })` show you ?

Comment: ya.......console.log(appUser); is giving null ..I dont know why it is not getting value..

Comment: seems you may be accessing it before it's set. potentially a race condition. ensure that the user is valid before accessing it

Comment: so any solution ?

Comment: got it.. Actually I was using 'users' in firebase and in get method ,I was using 'user' method. Thanks all for your help.